# PHP MySQL access not working in root of website

Tags: php, mysql

I've had a look through other's questions but couldn't see anything quite the same, so apologies if I missed one.

I created a site in a subdirectory while I was developing it before moving it to the root, on moving it to the root, access to MySQL database through php stopped working. The particular line of code that it stops at is

```
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=NAME;host=127.0.0.1","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
```

The script works fine as soon as it's moved even a single directory outside of the root. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,500,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/ProtoStyle_1.css"/>
    <?php
        require_once('./php/autoloader.php');
        $feed = new SimplePie('http://mywebsite.eu/blog/feed');

        function returnImage ($text) {
            $text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $pattern = "/<img[^>]+\>/i";
            preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
            $text = $matches[0];
            return $text;
        }


        function scrapeImage($text) {
            $pattern = '/src=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)[\'" >]/';
            preg_match($pattern, $text, $link);
            $link = $link[1];
            $link = urldecode($link);
            return $link;
        }
    ?>
</head>

<?php flush(); ?>

<body onresize="setFontSize()"  >
    <div id="kvh_page"> 
        <div id="kvh_header"><?php include("nav-bar.html"); ?></div>

        <div id="kvh_content">
            <div id="kvh_latestproject">
                <div class="kvh_screen" >
                    <div class="kvh_page1">
                        <img src="/assets/images/balloons.png"/>
                        <h1>Current Project</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="kvh_page2">
                        <img src="/assets/images/left-right.jpg"/>
                        <h1>Left/Right</h1>
                        <h2>Left/Right is a mobile app designed to push your reaction speed to the limit.</h2>
                        <a href="/projects/leftright"><button type="button">More</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>

            <div id="kvh_latestblog">
                <div>
                    <div class="kvh_screen" >
                        <div class="kvh_page1">
                            <img src="/assets/images/road.png"/>
                            <h1>Latest Blog Post</h1>
                        </div>
                        <?php $item = $feed->get_item();
                                    $Description = $item->get_description();
                                    $image = returnImage($Description);
                                    $Description = str_replace($image, "", $Description);
                                    $image = scrapeImage($image); ?>    

                        <div class="kvh_page2" style="background-image: url('<?php print $image; ?>')"> 
                            <span class="kvh_textmask">
                                <h1><?php print $item->get_title(); ?></h1>
                                <h2><?php print $Description; ?></h2>
                                <?php $author = $item->get_author(); ?>
                                <h3>Posted on <?php print $item->get_date('j F, Y'); ?> by <strong><?php print $author->get_name(); ?></strong></h3>
                                <a href="<?php print $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><button type="button">Read more</button></a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="kvh_latestresource">
                <div> 
                    <div class="kvh_screen" >
                        <div class="kvh_page1">
                            <img src="/assets/images/rain.png"/>
                            <h1>Thing of the day</h1>
                        </div>
                        <?php include("gethomestuff.php"); ?>
                        <!--<div class="kvh_page2" style="background-image: url('/assets/images/MangaDice.png')">

                            <span class="kvh_textmask">
                                <h1>This is the name of the thing</h1>
                                <h2>- Category</h2>
                                <a href="#"><button type="button">Check it out</button></a>
                            </span>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>                      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
    <script src="/assets/scripts/proto1.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

gethomestuff

```
<?php
    try {
    $pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=NAME;host=127.0.0.1","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    } 
    $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM DailyStuff limit 1"); 
    $statement->execute(); 
    $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach($results as $row) 
    {  
        if(strlen($row['Image']) < 10) 
            echo '<div class="kvh_page2">'. PHP_EOL; 
        else echo '<div class="kvh_page2" style="background-image: url(\''. $row['Image'] . '\')">'. PHP_EOL ;   
        echo '<span class="kvh_textmask">'. PHP_EOL . '<h1>'. $row['Name'].'</h1>'. PHP_EOL . '<h2>- '. $row['Category'] .'</h2>' . PHP_EOL .'<a href="'.$row['Link']. '"><button type="button">Check it out</button></a>'. PHP_EOL .'</span>'. PHP_EOL .'</div>' . PHP_EOL; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: one line of code isn't enough. Check for errors.

Comment: That statement is not in any way related to the location of the script, so its something else. Does this code get included from another script file in the scripts that use the database?

Comment: That line of code is the first line of the script. It never makes it past that when called from the root. 

There are no errors in that line if that's what you meant, as it works fine elsewhere, otherwise I'm not really sure what errors to check for or how?

Comment: Do you mean the `root` directory of your disk, or the `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: The script that this code is in gets included in my index.php file like so <?php include("gethomestuff.php"); ?> but it's the only one that uses the database. Not sure if that answers your questions Riggs?

Comment: Did you also move the `gethomestuff.php` file to the same folder as the `index.php` file

Comment: I think DocumentRoot? I'm new enough to web development so I'm not 100% sure which is which. It's displayed as "public_html" to me.

Comment: Yes they're in the same folder.

Comment: I'll guess your folder structure, paths & the rest of your code, if you can guess what my password is. Oh wait, my password for which site? Which folder on which site? Pardon the sarcasm here, but you left us nothing to go on and this question is already 1/2 hour into it with still no solution. Can you guess my shoesize? There, the answer is "no" because you can't see where I am and you can't see my feet, yet alone what kind of shoes I like to wear. So please, when you post a question, post as much information first, rather than leaving it to guesswork. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Grrr, you tell 'im Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: Use `phpinfo();` inside each file to figure out what your paths are to what file. Also use error reporting inside all your files http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Seems like we now know what we're dealing with now Smokey @RiggsFolly - Oneliners just doesn't make the cut ;-) I don't have enough fingers to count how many I've seen unclear questions today.

Comment: I think I spotted the most likely culprit, `require_once('./php/autoloader.php');` Code indictates the OP has some `code chops` but the question certainly contradicts that, so I am guessing lots of internet search... copy ... paste. Without much time spent understanding what was copied

Comment: Sounds good to me Smokey ^ - @RiggsFolly error reporting will tell them as would `phpinfo();` to figure out their paths.

Comment: I assume `phpinfo();` and error reporting should both go inside both my index.php and my gethomestuff.php?

Comment: all your files ^ and view your HTML source also. There could be errors that will show up in there also.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hm... some, but I doubt that. I've many shared hosting sites that let me use it.

Comment: `phpinfo()` seems to have worked, but I'm not sure what exactly I should be looking for in it?

Comment: If your files require a full system path, you will see something like `/var/usr/you/public_html/folder/file.php`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Sorry 2am here, and I cannot spend all night faffin with this. And its startin to look like an allnighter See you later @Fred-ii-

Comment: I'm not far behind you Smokey @RiggsFolly been a very long day and a most interesting one at that. *arrivederci!*

Comment: My system path is `/home/username/public_html/gethomestuff.php`

Comment: you wouldn't happen to have 2x index files in the root would you? One like index.php and one index.html ? Plus, error reporting didn't throw you anything? Plus `host=127.0.0.1` you can try `host=localhost`. I don't know what else to say, I am out of options at this point, except... Also, add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, see if it yields anything.

Comment: Didn't realise about the display errors part so this is the error I ended up having `Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/username/public_html/gethomestuff.php on line 5`.

Comment: Now that I know what's wrong I can search for a solution as it seems there's already questions about that problem. Thanks for the help, and sorry for the ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check the result of all calls to the database so change that line of code to

```
try {
    $pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=NAME;host=127.0.0.1","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo 'Database connection OK';
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

This should show you the error that is being generated by the attempt to connect to the database.

Comment: Where should this error be displayed? I've updated the file and tried both index.php and just going straight to gethomestuff.php but nothing is being output at all.

Comment: So how to do run this `index.php` show me what you enter into the browser address bar

Comment: www.mywebsite.eu/index.php or alternatively www.mywebsite.eu/gethomestuff.php

Comment: Paste all you code into the question along with filenames

Comment: I have changed the code a bit. This should now show a message on the browser window whether the connection suceeds or fails

Comment: I bet this has got something to do with your problem `require_once('./php/autoloader.php');` show the code for that script and also check you moved that directory as well

Comment: Still nothing being output despite the changed code.

Comment: I don't think that should be an issue, as the rest of the page is working up until the `gethomestuff.php`, and I have another page also located in the same folder which doesn't have the `require_once`, but tries to access the same database with a similar file to `gethomestuff.php` and doesn't work either. Want me to post it regardless?

Comment: Oh bear in mind the error message would appear in the section of your page titled `<h1>Thing of the day</h1>`

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but nothing's coming up in there, even after including `error_reporting(E_ALL);` which I assume was the correct level?

Comment: @Kaevan you need to "display" them too by adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` as stated under your question.

Comment: Sorry only saw that after. 

So my error is `Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/username/public_html/gethomestuff.php on line 5`

Comment: Which now gives me something to search for, thanks for the help guys.